# Как получить картинки из файла .htaccess с инструкцией `deny from all`?

Tags: .htaccess, php, администрирование

Пробовал у себя на Денвере защитить каталог с картинками от доступа через адресную строку. Создал файл `.htaccess` с инструкцией "`deny from all`" и поместил его в каталог `images`. Но после этого и браузер не смог вытащить оттуда картинки. (консоль: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`). Как правильно поставить такую защиту?

Comment: Дурацкий вопрос: а зачем? Если картинки покажет браузер, то их и любой юзер получит :) Разве что убивать ссылки с других сайтов, но тогда при чём тут адресная строка?

Comment: У меня сайт mySite.com. В корневом каталоге есть папка images. Юзер пришел в браузере http://mySite.com/images - бац - ему на экране список файлов этого каталога. ОНО ЕМУ НАДО?

Comment: Делов-то :) Options -Indexes в .htaccess. Если это запрещено на хостинге, то просто положить туда пустой index.php.

Comment: Вот это уже дело! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не так делается, это называется `hot link protection`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

[вот туториал](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=122057)

Comment: Хм. У меня referrer режется в браузере всегда, меня не пустит?

Comment: конечно, я правда немного удивлен что это вас не напрягает, с другой стороны каждый сам себе хозяин, у меня тоже фэйсбук не работает в elinks, и по моему Цукерберг не сильно переживает.

Comment: А зачем два выражения? Выражение  

    ^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$
включает в себя  

    ^http://(www\.)?localhost
А в данном контексте использования они полностью равнозначны, но  

    ^http://(www\.)?localhost
производительнее.  
А вообще лучше так:  

    ^http://(?:www\.)?localhost(?:/.*)?$

Comment: пример просто чтобы указать что несколько хостов сделать можно

Comment: @eicto, на соответствующей теме больше не дают возможности комментировать. Я о том,что хватит придираться. Под константой в js я имел в виду переменную, которую определяют в начале скрипта( желательно ОЧЕНЬ большими символами) и обращаются к ней из всевозможных и невозможных функций скрипта.